Rule to simplify $\det{(X \: \text{diag}(\psi) \: X')}$ where X is not a square matrix?
Are there any known results/simplifications for an expression of the way
$$\det{(X \: \text{diag}(\psi) \: X')} \:,$$
where X is a $n \times m$ matrix? I am aware that the determinant of a diagonal matrix can be written as
$$\det{(\Psi)} = \prod_{i = 1}^{m} \Psi_{ii} \:,$$
where $\Psi = \text{diag}(\psi)$.
My goal is to end up with an expression which is log-linear in $\rho$ as the determinant is passed to an solver for linear optimization problems. I tried rewriting the expression using a Kronecker product.

You seem to have switched back and forth between $ \psi $ and $ \rho $, give your post & title a proofread.

What does log-linear in $\rho$ (or $\psi$) mean?

Thanks for the hint, I edited the post.
My ultimate goal is to optimize over $\psi$ given $X$, where the optimization tool I use only accepts linear objective functions. I can rewrite $\log{(\det{(\Psi)})}$ as a sum, which is what I need. However, I can't figure out a way how to arrive at a similar expression, when the diagonal matrix is embedded in the given multiplicative form.

See this as a generalization of the Cauchy Binet formula. It may be helpful here.
